# Is there a limit for this?

Tags: c#, controls

Okay, so I was not allowed to comment on the post I found to ask the author of the question this so hopefully Sergey(Sorry if I misspelled) sees this. I have 8 Label controls being dynamically made and when I use the code he provided:

```
            foreach (Label lbl in Controls.OfType<Label>())
        {
            if (lbl.Tag.ToString() == "Mass")
            {
                Controls.Remove(lbl);
            }
        }
```

it will remove 5 of the 8 labels created. All have the same tag as well. I will have to run the same code 3 times for it to work and each time it runs, the amount removed decreases. Very sorry for asking this as question.

Comment: No, there's no limit (Within reason), only performance impact when you start to get into high ranges of updates.

Comment: is there a limit for what? your 8 labels?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.  Please put some effort into a meaningful title and body

Comment: You should include how, where & when did the labels create. You probably have issues with the order of events between label create to remove.

Comment: By the way, you are developing ASP.NET Webform, right? You should tag the application type you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

First off, when reiterating a question from another author, it is often helpful to link the original post. And put the question in the post as well as the title.

There is no limit to the number of times a foreach can iterate. The problem is that you are changing the number of values in the list with each iteration, so each time it you remove a value, it decreases the threshold of completion (Remember, a "foreach" loop is just a nicely packaged "for" loop).

There are 2 easy solutions to this problem:

Solution 1 - Create a temporary copy to iterate through

```
    foreach (Label lbl in Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList())
    {
        if (lbl.Tag.ToString() == "Mass")
        {
            Controls.Remove(lbl);
        }
    }
```

Solution 2 - User a more traditional "for" loop (This requires you to decrement however)

```
    for(int i = 0; i < Controls.OfType<Label>().Count; i++)
    {
        Label lbl = Controls.OfType<Label>()[i];
        if (lbl.Tag.ToString() == "Mass")
        {
            Controls.Remove(lbl);
            i--;
        }
    }
```

Im actually surprised you aren't getting a System.InvalidOperationException for trying to modify an IEnumerable.

Comment: Alright, yeah sorry, I suck with postings and try not to use Stackoverflow that often cause, yeah. Thank you and again, sorry

Comment: Solution 2 is invalid. `OfType<T>` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` which means that there is A. No `Count` **property** and B. No indexer. To match what you have, you'd have to replace with `Count()` and `ElementAt(int)` which would then  have to keep re-iterating the entire collection. You can fix both of those by storing the result of `OfType<Label>().ToList()` (or `ToArray()`) in a temporary variable *prior* to iteration.